# How to dynamically add attributes to an interface

Tags: python, plone, zope.interface

I need to add an attribute for every attribute in an interface. So I am trying to dynamically modify it to add them, but not with much success for now.

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
class IMember(Interface):
    first_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'first name')
    last_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'last name')
```

And I would like to modify it like that:

```
class IMember(Interface):
    first_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'first name')
    last_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'last name')
    visbility_first_name = schema.Bool(title=u'Display: first name')
    visbility_last_name = schema.Bool(title=u'Display: last name')
```

I tried modifying the class afterwards, but as it was already initialized, the schema was set and I was not sure how to change it. I also thought about writing a directive (e.g.: interface.Implements()) but it seems quite complicated to do just to add attributes.

My final goal is to add a z3c.form fieldset with a set of Bool widgets.

So, is there a way to do it in Python, or do I have to modify the interface and add all the attributes manually ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure your additional attributes need to be first class fields on the schema? Maybe [Tagged Values](https://developer.plone.org/components/interfaces.html#tagged-values) on the interface could work for you.

Comment: Sorry, on mobile, having trouble posting the right links: http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html#tagged-values

Comment: My final goal is to have a fieldset in z3c.form with a set of Bool widgets. I don't think tagged values will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a dynamic subclass of the interface using the `InterfaceClass` metatype.

Create a dictionary of the additional schema fields:

```
fields = {}
for name, attr in IMember.namesAndDescriptions():
    if isinstance(attr, schema.Field):
        fields['visible_' + name] = schema.Bool(title=u'Display: ' + attr.title)
```

Now you can create a dynamic interface subclassing your existing interface:

```
from zope.interface.interface import InterfaceClass

IMemberExtended = InterfaceClass('IMemberExtended', (IMember,), fields)
```

This can all be wrapped up in a class decorator if you so desire:

```
from zope.interface.interface import InterfaceClass
from zope import schema

def add_visibility_fields(iface):            
    fields = {}
    for name, attr in iface.namesAndDescriptions():
        if isinstance(attr, schema.Field):
            fields['visible_' + name] = schema.Bool(title=u'Display: ' + attr.title)

    return InterfaceClass(iface.__name__, (iface,), fields)
```

which you'd use on your existing interface:

```
@add_visibility_fields
class IMember(Interface):
    first_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'first name')
    last_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'last name')
```

This creates a subclass; you can also *replace* the whole interface with the generated interface:

```
def add_visibility_fields(iface):            
    fields = {}
    for name, attr in iface.namesAndDescriptions():
        fields[name] = attr
        if isinstance(attr, schema.Field):
            fields['visible_' + name] = schema.Bool(title=u'Display: ' + attr.title)

    return InterfaceClass(iface.__name__, iface.__bases__, fields)
```

Demo of that last version:

```
>>> @add_visibility_fields
... class IMember(Interface):
...     first_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'first name')
...     last_name = schema.TextLine(title=u'last name')
... 
>>> IMember.names()
['visible_last_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'visible_first_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use python's metaclasses. Use of a custom metaclass will allow you to modify the creation of a class, so you can dynamically add or modify attributes upon/before class creation. For an excellent SO answer on metaclasses see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1507867).

However you should try and restructure your program to avoid having to use metaclasses. Typically they should *only* be used if you really know you need them. In your case, is it possible to modify `schema.TextLine` to allow the behavior you want (perhaps by adding a hook)?

Comment: `zope.interface` already makes heavy use of metaclasses though, it'll be... tricky to integrate with that.

Comment: Yeah, using metaclasses is tricky to begin with, I can't even imagine how much of a headache trying to do metaclass inheritance must be... All the more reason to find a solution that doesn't involve them!

Comment: Yeah it seems quite complicated to implement, having an easier solution would be great :).

Comment: @FastTurtle: You can just use the metaclass to produce a new interface object; see my answer.

Comment: @FastTurtle: also note that a Zope and Plone lean *heavily* on interfaces and schemas; avoiding these would be akin to trying to swim up a waterfall.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your answer looks great. I like your class decorator and usage of Zope's `InterfaceClass`. I think I'll steal this pattern for the future haha.